# How to Deploy Eclipse servlet in mozilla or chrome browser?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, browser

I have create My First "Hello World" Servlet in Eclipse. It is running properly in Eclipse Browser.

and I'm using Apache Tomcat, and it is also running properly.

Please tell me how to deploy my Servlet in Web browser like Internet Explorer, Chrome, Mozilla Firefox etc..

I don't want to deploy my servlet in Eclipse browser.

My
Localhost:8080 is running properly.
and my jsp pages is also working in Tomcat, 
tell me how to deploy my Servlet in Web browser?
i don't know how to deploy in web browser.
Thank You